# Is this type of soliciting comment acceptable?

Tags: discussion, spam

From [ripper234's profile](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/355/ripper234?tab=activity):

> 14h   comment     What is a good strategy
>   for using the Doomsday card?
>
> If you
>   want more Magic experts to look at
>   your question, trying asking here:
>   draw3cards.com
>
> 15h    comment     What
>   should I buy to teach Magic, The
>   Gathering to someone ?
>
> This looks like
>   a great question for draw3cards.com
>
> 15h   comment     Why Does Magic Use The
>   “Paris Mulligan” Rule?
>
> This looks like
>   a great question for draw3cards.com
>
> Nov 5     comment     Magic: The Gathering
>   stack
>
> Note - see draw3cards.com
>
> Nov 5
>     comment     Why would you want to play
>   with a deck bigger than 60 cards in
>   MTG?
>
> Note - see draw3cards.com for a
>   dedicated Stack Exchange.

I believe this user actually owns/runs the (v.1) StackExchange site http://draw3cards.com. I sympathise with the desire to increase traffic. And it's true that the site might be of interest to the perusers of these questions.

But that doesn't change the fact that this is essentially (targeted) spam advertising. Potentially, a comment of this type could be left on every MTG question on this site.

Is this acceptable? Would it be acceptable if it wasn't a site powered by the Stack Overflow engine? What about if it was an 'official' MTG StackExchange site?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that in light of the 
discussion on Meta what I was doing was considered "ok". I will stop.
http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/207/whats-the-policy-for-questions-on-games-that-have-their-own-stackexchange-site

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in

https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion

> #### May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?
>
> Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant answers, and if they happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad sales team for details.

Basically in small doses, so long as the answer or comment *answers the question* this is generally OK. When it is all you see from that particular user, or it is randomly sprayed over every post that user sees, then ... not so much.

Answer (score 0):

Per Robert Cartaino, SE1 sites are not exempt from normal site policies.

As a consequence, the comments were removed.

<strike>A previous discussion (not dup, but related) is https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207/whats-the-policy-for-questions-on-games-that-have-their-own-stackexchange-site</strike>

A couple issues for me:

1. **Links off to other sites** - We use these all the time, in general this is allowed..  In answers, a link to further information is relevant and useful.  *Tagging every question about a game with a link to go elsewhere doesn't strike me as great idea.*  If the link was in the form of an answer and explained further why that site would be better for that particular question I think it would be better.
2. **Disclosure** - It seems apparent that ripper is the owner of the site.  A SE1 site should not get a free pass from the disclosure requirements of the FAQ.

In short, I can tolerate this in small doses, but I don't want every MtG question to get a link off to another site.

Perhaps we should link to them in the tag wiki?